# Random sampling from large rasterlayer

Tags: r, raster

I have a large Rasterlayer with integers ranging from 0 to 44.

```
class       : RasterLayer
dimensions  : 29800, 34470, 1027206000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
extent      : 331300, 676000, 5681995, 5979995  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs
data source : /home/mkoehler/stk_rast_whz
names       : stk_rast_whz
values      : 0, 44  (min, max)
```

I want to do a stratified sampling of 5000 points per stratum.
I get the following error:

```
POINTS<-sampleStratified(b, size=5000, na.rm=T, xy=F)
(Error in ys[[i]] <- y : attempt to select less than one element)
```

Here is a code that reproduces the problems (even when only selecting 1
item per stratum):

```
 set.seed(10)
 r <- raster(ncol=5000, nrow=5000)
 names(r) <- 'stratum'
 r[] <- round((runif(ncell(r)))*44)

 sampleStratified(r, size=1,xy=T)

Error in ys[[i]] <- y : attempt to select less than one element
```

Trying that with fewer strata and changing the settings of "size" or
"exp" have no effect.
R version: [64-bit] C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.1

Any ideas?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Your example code runs fine for me (R 3.1.0, 32-bit)

Comment: Strange! Does that depend on the R version/Library versions I do use?

Comment: Might be. Check the version of your `raster` package. I'm using 2.2-31.

Comment: @koekenbakker my raster version is raster_2.3-12 
My collegues working with the same versions get the same error messages. I'll give it a try with the older version.

Comment: Yes, that would be a good idea. You can also try an older version of the code [here](https://github.com/cran/raster/blob/master/R/sampleStratified.R). Perhaps you can debug by running the code step-by-step and checking the output of each step.

Comment: @koekenbakker my guess is that on your system, the raster can be processed in memory and so you don't experience this problem (see my post below).

Comment: Good guess! And nicely explained the problem, thanks. Seems strange to use the values of a raster for indexing, could be negative as well. You're right, should be something like `for (i in 1:nrow(f))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug (as at `raster` 2.3-12), and occurs when (1) your raster contains cells with value `0`, and (2) the raster can't be processed in memory (i.e. `canProcessInMemory(r)` is `FALSE`).

The function loops over the unique cell values produced by `freq(r)`, and then indexes a list by each of these values in turn. If one of those values is zero, the error will be triggered since the 0th element does not exist. For example:

```
list()[[0]]
# Error in list()[[0]] : attempt to select less than one element]
```

You'll notice that the error doesn't occur if you fill `r` with, e.g., `r[] <- sample(44, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)`, since it won't have any zeroes.

When the raster *can* be processed in memory, the function loops over the row numbers of `freq(r)`, and so the subsequent list indexing is sensible.

I've contacted the maintainer to report this bug.

Meanwhile, as a temporary fix, you could use something like the following to make a corrected copy of the function (which will remain available in the current R session).

```
sampleStratified2 <- 
  eval(parse(text=sub('sr\\[, 2\\] == i', 'sr[, 2] == f[i, 1]',
                      sub('i in f\\[, 1\\]', 'i in seq_len(nrow(f))',
                          deparse(getMethod(sampleStratified, 
                                            signature='RasterLayer')@.Data))
  )))

sampleStratified2(r, size=1, xy=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, this has been fixed in raster version 2.3-20 (currently only available from R-Forge, on CRAN soon).

Comment: @RobertH great - thanks for addressing this so quickly.